# How to use matrix library in omnet

Tags: c++, matrix, omnet++, veins

I want to do matrix manipulation of the received data from the neighbor nodes using VEINS. So is there a matrix library in omnet? How can I do the matrix manipulation in omnet?

Answer (score 4):

You can choose whatever matrix manipulation library you prefer. OMNeT++ is a C++ class library so you can add any other C or C++ libraries to your project. There is really no restriction what you can use.

Comment: Thanks Rudi for your reply. I have used Eigen as a matrix library. How to assign the matrix variable to NULL.  I tried MatrixXd mat= NULL; but there is an error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Eigen::MatrixXd {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>}' requested
 MatrixXd mat= NULL;

Comment: @rakez if you have further questions, post them... any question posted in the comments will not help other SO users.